# Communication type between applications

Tags: c#, java, sockets, architecture, communication

I am about to develop a server using the `Java` language for a game.

The game is written in `C#`, and they are going to communicate through `sockets`.

The only way I can come up with is using `JSON`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Your question isn't very specific. What kind of communication? Persistent connection like in an online game? Or do you need non-persistent connection for occasional connections (i.e. submitting scores etc)?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to have either a RESTful or a SOAP-based web service on the server
side and the client to call it. This is also going through sockets on the lowest level.

If you want, you can implement socket-based communication yourself (no REST/SOAP)
but I would not recommend it as it will make your job more difficult and error-prone.
But on the other hand, this may be more efficient, if you implement it well.

So you have many options, it all depends on the exact needs/requirements.

Comment: The "problem way" indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate properly your applications, I suggest you think about a multi-threaded server, in which every worker thread should poll the open socket and deal with the request, and you should write all this with kind of low-level I/O and multi-threading APIs.

Though it is possible to do it, I must recommend you to leave your communications to an application server, for example a Tomcat server or something similar.  There you can deploy your java server as a web application implementing a REST or SOAP based webservice.

This way, you are covered with a production-strength server doing your communications duty for you, and can focus on writing a standard webservice client in C# (I admit I can be of little or no help at all in C#, but I guess someone here will be glad to help you there).

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a convenient API / library to communicate between apps, you may want to consider [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).

For webserver-client models. You may want to consider implementing a HTTP REST/SOAP interface.